# grails with intellij idea 2020.1

Tags: intellij-idea, grails3

I just downloaded yesterday ultimate release of intellij idea IDE, but there is no support for GRAILS, though in web documentation is told great support possible. IDEA assistance online is trying to help me but they refer to grails entry in project menu, or in plugin menu or others but there is no any grails entry in any idea setup.
Can anyone help me how to import/enable preliminary grails support in brand new IJ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have **Grails** bundled plugin enabled for Grails support:

[image]